# Call function before the href Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to call a function on a click event before the href is invoked. I want to do this so that I can set a value to a given variable and then when I redirect to the new page I can access that variable via `this.$parent.varName`. This is what I'm trying to do but it won't call the function:

```
<a @click="openWorkflow(rec.id)" href="#/workflows">Edit</a>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here and/or if this is the right way to achieve what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take care of redirecting to the next page inside the `openWorkflow` function, then you can place it directly wherever you need it to be in the logic. If you're using vue-router, you can do this by just running `router.push("#/workflows")`. If you're not, you can still do the standard `window.location.href = 'baseurl.com/#workflows'`.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the base_url. I was trying to to href inside the function by `window.location.href = '#/workflows'` . I needed to add the base url

Comment: Hey @Nickel, the solution you gave me worked although, I was able to set the value of a variable in the vue which was responsible for the redirection but I couldn't access that variable in the next component using `this.$parent.varName`. Is there a way to send in some data along with redirection?